# Question about Michelson Interferometer

Tags: optics, reflection, interferometry

[image]

In Michelson Interferometer, the mirror that lies in the middle (half-silvered mirror), can reflect and let through light. But the light after being reflected by the half-silvered mirror, only let light through.(they don't show the blue line that I draw) Also, the orange line do not pass through. I want to know how the mirror works and why the reflected light only pass through the mirror.

Comment: Unclear exactly what you are asking, but - only half of the light coming back gets reflected as well (they just don't bother pointing that out because that light is lost and does nothing for the experiment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semi-silvered mirror is what is referred to as a 50/50 beam splitter. Half the light is reflected and half transmitted. The blue line you have drawn depicts the overlap of the secondary reflected green beam and the secondary transmitted orange beam. This is not shown on the diagram as it is not the overlapped beam used to measure any interference. The purple beam shows the reflected-transmitted green beam overlapped with the transmitted-reflected orange beam. Since the experimenter has decided to place a detector on this path it is the only overlapped beam shown.

Answer (score 1):

Your blue line shows the path that the green and orange lines will take. The black line also shows the path the green and orange will take.